# How to pass touched label text to gesture recognizer selector method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an UITableView and I'm using UITableViewCell class for cells. Inside cells, I'm using labels to display company data.

What I need is to open company website in browser when user clicks on the company title, or to open mail app when user cliks on an email address displayed (but nothing should happen when user touches any other part of the cell).

I have everything working ok technically (gesture recognizer, opening safari and mail etc.) except one "small" thing. I can not figure out how can I pass those urls (web or email) to touchrecognizer selector methods.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assign to label tag a ID of company model (in a some array), then in gesture recognizer delegate you can find associated company in array by ID.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can get the tap position in your table view, and further get indexPath of the position.

```
- (void) handleGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint tapPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:self.tableView];
    // Do whatever you want with indexPath.section, indexPath.row information
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
UILabel *currentLabel = (UILabel *) tap.view;
NSString *labelText= currentLabel.text;
   }
```

You can try this.. This works for me!!

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is static you can put an invisible button on the company title label.

And in the action give a tag to every button equal to rowAtIndexPath.

Here your int tag=button.tag;

Now if you are getting your website links in an array then :

In the button action fetch the link as

```
NSString *urlString=[websteArray objectAtIndex:tag];
                    OR
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",[websteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSLog(@"the strurl is %@",urlString);



[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```